# Display product variations on category page

Tags: woocommerce

How do I show all product variations on WooCommerce category pages?

I have set up a variable product with three variations. I want each variation (not the variable product itself) to be displayed as a separate product on the product category page. The user should be able to open a variable product and add it to the cart.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Example : http://bennyhendrikx.be/product-categorie/clothing/page/2/

Add this code in youre functions.php

```
   if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' ) ) {

  function woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    if ($product->product_type == "variable" && (is_product() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag())) {
      woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart();
    }

    else {
      woocommerce_get_template( 'loop/add-to-cart.php' );
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_single_variation', 5);
function woocommerce_template_single_variation() {
            global $product;
            if ($product->product_type == "variable" && (is_product_category() || is_product_tag())) {
              echo woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart();
            }

 }
```

Comment: This doesn't show separate products, this just prints the variations within the product

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can just paste this code in your theme functions.php

here is code

```
/**
 * Replace add to cart button in the loop.
 */
function iconic_change_loop_add_to_cart() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'iconic_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}

add_action( 'init', 'iconic_change_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );

/**
 * Use single add to cart button for variable products.
 */
function iconic_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    if ( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart();
        return;
    }

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'iconic_loop_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );

    woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();
}

/**
 * Customise variable add to cart button for loop.
 *
 * Remove qty selector and simplify.
 */
function iconic_loop_variation_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;

    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0" />
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even after so many years this one is not so simple for woocommerce.
The above examples shows the parent products with available variations below.
You maybe want to show the variations as simple products.
It's better to use a plugin for this. The Woocommerce single variations by weLaunch https://www.welaunch.io/en/product/woocommerce-single-variations/
it's the best i found so far. It gives you the opportunity to even exclude one variation from the category page (Most of the times, your products have 2 variations color/size. You simple want to show only the color variation).
If you want to go with custom code. You have to keep in mind, the images, pagination, filters, product links with variation parameters.
Woocommerce works with parent products on its core.